# Using HashMap in second thread when first thread is finished

Tags: java, multithreading, hashmap

If I run thread 1 and create a HashMap in it, can I read and/or modify it in thread 2 when thread 1 is finished?

---

```
// thread A
// stuff
new BukkitRunnable() {
  public void run() {
    final Map<String,Boolean> map = new HashMap<String,Boolean>();
    // fill it with data...
    new BukkitRunnable() {
      public void run() {
        // use the map
      }
    }.runTask(plugin); // Running it on thread A 0.05 sec later.
  }
}.runTaskAsynchronously(plugin); // Running it on a new thread
```

Comment: Uh, sure? Is there some code that you're having problems with?

Answer (score 2):

As long as you have a *happens-before* barrier between the last update of the `Map` in thread 1 and the first access of the `Map` in thread 2. Otherwise the memory-cache of the CPU running thread 2 may not see the changes.

See [Memory Consistency Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility) in the javadoc.

So, just the fact that thread 1 has finished is not enough. Now if you don't *start* thread 2 until after the `Map` is complete, you're good, since `start()` establishes such a *happens-before* relation.

Alternatively, it depends on *how* the `Map` reference is shared between the threads.

Comment: I've posted some code, could you tell me if that'd work?